# CSS first div dynamic width

Tags: html, css, dynamic, width

is there any solution to make the first div with dynamic width?
Trick with overflow:hidden does not work, because i need it (div.first) in the first place:

```
<div id="wrapper"><div class="first></div><div class="second"></div><div>
```

What is the best solution that would work in older versions of IE?

Thank you for any help

Comment: What does "dynamic width" mean? What does "older versions" mean? Please be specific.

Comment: older mean: IE 8,7,6 and dynamic width: when the .second will have a width 50px then .first adapts by wrapper (responsive layout)

Comment: @DanielKopťák  are the inner divs side by side or one on top of the other?

Comment: overflow:hidden works when you use margin-left: -50px or something like that

Comment: side by side, and negativ values (-50px) i think, wrong displays in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use absolute positioning to do this

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
  width:    100%;
  position: relative;
}

.one {
  position: absolute;
  left:     0;
  right:    50px;
}

.two {
  position: absolute;
  right:    0;
  width:    50px;
}
```

there are nicer ways when you don't have to support the old IEs :-)

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this solution?

```css
body{margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px;}
#right {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    float:right;
}
#right_absolute{
  background-color: blue;
  float:right;width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}

#left{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right_absolute"></div>
</div>
```

I need it for better SEO. I want div.left (content) as much as possible on top of the code. The right column is not so important for SEO...